# Issue with mysql query when changing value to a variable

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$results = mysql_query("select * from doctorlist where assignednumber = '1231231234' ");
```

I need to change the number 1231231234 to a variable. If I change it to the code below it does not work. I have displayed the variable on the page so I know it is set.

```
$results = mysql_query("select * from doctorlist where assignednumber = '$phoneNumber' ");
```

Could someone please help. I know it is a small issue, but have been unable to fix it.

Comment: There is bogus data in the variable or it is a bogus variable - the question is then: *what* does the variable evaluate to at the time of interpolation? In any case, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php for cleaners/safer ways to write such a query.

Comment: try `echo("select * from doctorlist where assignednumber = '$phoneNumber' ");`

Comment: just `echo $phoneNumber`, your problem will likely fall there

Comment: What you want is known as parametrization, and it is supported by the MySQLi and PDO extensions. You can read up on them [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/)

Comment: @Asad you're talking about PDO prepared tsatements but I think he has different problem and doesn't need PDO.

Comment: @infinity it seemed to me as though he wanted to introduce a variable value into a query, so I suggested he use parametrization (not necessarily PDO, MySQLi does fine too)

Comment: @Asad I totally agree with your comment but I think his variable is either bogus or he has array/object not string/int and that is causing the problem.

Comment: The $phonenumber variable is passed from my phone system. I can echo the variable and it displays the correct number. I just can't get it to do the query based on the variable

Comment: Good, so there is a value in the variable; is there also a record in doctorlist that has the same value for the column assignednumber?

Comment: Yes the number that the variable is set to is in the assignednumber column

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps split it like this

```
$sql_query = "select * from doctorlist where assignednumber='$phoneNumber'";
$results = mysql_query($sql_query);
```

or

```
$sql_query = "select * from doctorlist where assignednumber='".$phoneNumber."' ";
$results = mysql_query($sql_query);
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your variable type with var_dump($phoneNumber) than do the following:

```
$results = mysql_query("select * from doctorlist where assignednumber = '".$phoneNumber."' ");
```

to improve readability and last if you expect an Integer cast your variable like:

```
(int)$phoneNumber
```

or if string do

```
mysql_real_escape_string($phoneNumber)
```

Comment: Instead of concatenating a double quoted string with a variable, it's clearer to just put the variable in the string. E.g. "this is $my_var." vs "this is ".$my_var."."

Comment: @Greg that's up to personal preference it's not a rule so I agree with you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the variable inside the query like this:

'{$phoneNumber}'